# How to simulate 'dragstart' and 'dragend' event in Google Map Rectangle Element?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to detect Google Map API - `rectangle`'s `dragstart` and `dragend` events for doing two-ways data binding in Angular.

But I find out that Google Map API v3 do not have `drag`, `dragstart`, `dragend` event for `Rectangle`, how can I simulate those events?

It's seems that Google Map Rectangle isn't a DOM, I can't easily do this like a DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `mousedown` and `mouseup` you can simulate drag by logging x and y co-ordinates.

Comment: Google Maps doesn't have `mousedown` or `mouseup` events.